# .Net LoginControls - User can't logout in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, authentication, login-control

Basically, the logout link doesn't do anything, but only in Firefox. (I can login and out freely from other browsers) There really isn't a whole lot of information I can really give other than that, since I'm still new to this project and .net as a whole, and know almost nothing about the login controls.

So if someone else has experienced a similar issue in the past, and can recognize the issue with the little info I have, that would be great! If not, sorry for the lack of depth, but its all I have.

If it helps, here is the code for where the logout link is:

```
<LoggedInTemplate>
    ...
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Anonymous/Login.aspx" />
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you check out the asp.net authentication cookie being there during the session (can use firebug, for example) and whether it is being flushed on logout?

Comment: There's only a sessionId cookie, and a cookie with the name of our project. When I click on the logout button, neither of the cookies are affected, but for some reason it then shows an error somewhere else in the page. I'm going to take a look at that and see if its the problem.